# Firefox won't play Youtube videos anymore

Tags: macos, firefox, firefox-extensions, youtube, osx-mavericks

I use Firefox as default browser on my Mac. For some reason I can't play Youtube videos anymore. Facebook videos work, and Youtube videos play fine in Safari. If I restart with all addons disabled, it works again. Then if I enable addons one by one, it works up til a certain moment. Then I disable the last addon again, but no luck. Then I disable all addons manually, and still no luck.

What happens is I see a black screen with "static". See the image:

[image: Youtube Static]

So I'm a bit lost here. What is the best way to solve this? How can I get this working again? Below the list of the addons I have installed.

- Adblock Plus
- Better privacy
- Calomel SSL Validation
- Date Picker / Calendar
- DNS cache
- Downthemall
- Empty cache button
- Flash and video download
- HTTP fox
- HTTPS Everywhere
- Lucifox
- Mailvelope
- Master Password +
- PWgen
- QR Code image generator
- Quickfox notes
- Quick passwords
- Saved password editor
- Soundcloud Downloader
- Tab mix plus

Comment: When you enable them one by one, which one causes YouTube to not work anymore?

Comment: I have never used OS X, but I think you should try disabling all of those add-ons (then see if you can watch You-Tube, from there,re-enable each one until You-Tube no longer functions, I think you should be able to figure out from that if that is the issue or not.

Comment: @SPRBRN I do have one question for you though, were there any error codes or messages that popped up and mentioned a problem?

Comment: I've added an image of what happens when I open a Youtube video. I know the principle of enabling the addons one by one. The problem is that this method doesn't work. Say I do this alphabetically, then up til a certain addon, it works, then it stop working. So you think that this last addon is the problem. I disable that addon, but no, it doesn't work. Then I disable the previous, no change. Then I disable all manually, but not via the safe restart, no change, no video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem for a long time, and I figured it out the hard way.

I encountered this problem whenever I'm on youtube with SSL enabled, and there was no issue while using an http only connection. And it seems flash plugin will establish a connection on its own to stream the videos. The flash client always throws an error when some special cipher suites used in the browser SSL configuration are disabled (RC4/SHA, RC4/MD5) in your browser. The RC4 cipher suites are weak and some add-ons disable them by default for security reasons.

From your add-ons list you have HTTPS everywhere (which would default to https youtube) and Calomel SSL validation (which can disable RC4 cipher suites). 
It is no fault of the add-ons that video breaks, and it is good to disable RC4. What I'm not sure is to put the blame on a crappy flash client or a youtube stream server that cannot handle modern cipher suites.

In short : go to about:config, search for `security.ssl3.` and find out the entries for `rsa_rc4_128_sha`/`rsa_rc4_128_md5` and set them to `true`. Reload youtube, and you are good to go. Most likely Calomel will reset those after a restart. But I think there are options to allow all cipher suites in calomel preferences.

EDIT : The reason you saw the problem even after disabling the add-ons is that calomel might not reset the cipher suite settings after removing.

Comment: Disabling HTTPS Everywhere for Youtube does the trick. Not how I would like it, but it's good to know this solution! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Under Firefox: Complements->Plugins->Shockwave Flash, you need deactivate or uncheck the option "Activate Protect Mode Adobe Flash". Then restart Firefox. You can play YouTube videos again.

Comment: OP said **If I restart with all addons disabled, it works again.** which means there is no problem with plugins, its an addon which is causing problem